# BrainTree Drop In 3D Secure - payload.liabilityShifted not in payload

Tags: braintree

im trying to turn on 3D Secure in my brain tree drop in initialisation but its failing inside the `paymentRequestMethod` as the payload never returns a `liabilityShifted` property;

```
braintree.dropin.create({
    authorization: button.attr("data-client-token"),
    container: "#dropin-container",
    threeDSecure: {
        amount: Number(document.querySelector('[data-chargeable]')).toFixed(2),
    }
}, function( createErr, instance ) {
    button.on("click", function() {
        instance.requestPaymentMethod(function(requestPaymentMethodErr, payload) {
            console.log(payload);
            nonce = null;
            if(requestPaymentMethodErr) {
                return;
            }
            if (payload.liabilityShifted || payload.type !== 'CreditCard') {
                nonce = payload.nonce;
                button.hide();
                payButton.show();
            } else {
                button.hide();
                instance.clearSelectedPaymentMethod();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

No matter what card I use from the selection the liability shifted is not in the payload and the type is always credit card;

```
{
    binData: {
        commercial: "Unknown",
        countryOfIssuance: "Unknown",
        debit: "Unknown",
        durbinRegulated: "Unknown",
        healthcare: "Unknown",
        issuingBank: "Unknown",
        payroll: "Unknown",
        prepaid: "Unknown",
        productId: "Unknown",
    },
    description: "ending in 11",
    details: {
        bin: "411111", 
        lastTwo: "11", 
        lastFour: "1111", 
        cardType: "Visa"
    },
    nonce: "tokencc_bf_95mrgx_75kwgh_d3qbzb_qy9vq3_b27",
    type: "CreditCard"
}
```

Can anyone advise what I am doing wrong.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

[`liabilityShifted`](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/3d-secure/client-side/#advanced-client-side-options) indicates that 3D Secure worked and authentication succeeded. You will also want to ensure that you are using the [3D Secure test cards](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/3d-secure/testing-go-live/#testing) to result in the expected 3D Secure response. To get the `liabilityShifted` response in the payload, you will instead need to use the [`verifyPayload`](https://braintree.github.io/braintree-web/current/ThreeDSecure.html#~verifyPayload) object.